# do I really need dust caps for laptop ports e.g. USB audio/mic jack?

Tags: laptop

I don't know if it's a kind of OCD or if it's really helpful when you work outside with your laptop and environment around might have liquid or water moisture or spill or dust or something else (gas or liquid) that might possibly go into the laptop through the ports.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do, moisture can corrode the metal, grit can scratch and eventually wear through the thin metal as well when plugging something in and out. In theory the whole thing could get clogged, or as in your question liquid or dirt could enter the laptop and play havoc.

There are (very expensive) laptops made specifically for field work, these have caps for everything for this very reason.

Comment: then what is the reason for some non-bulky and fancy laptop that claims to pass military tests and meet the military standard while they do not have any attached caps for any of the ports?

Comment: new thinkpad carbon X1 for example.

Comment: @cuckold: marketing weasels speak with forked tongue.

Comment: @cuckodlyou: Those military standards are nothing to do with moisture or liquid resistance. They're basically just drop tests.

Comment: but they clearly claim and test to endure water spill on keyboard, together with other tests - dust / sand exposure for couple of hours

Comment: You might be able to purchase a silicone jacket thing similar to ones for mobile phones.

Comment: I'm unsure on the military tests bit, the only military ones I'm familiar with first hand was NZ army laptops and they were fully protected, shock resistant cases, rubber (or rubberlike) caps over everything. And the Electric Power company here has similar bulky and well protected ones.